# How to fix a crack in laminate countertop

Tags: crack, countertops, laminate

I just finished installing mitered Formica counter-tops for the first time.  After I was all finished I realized I must have cracked the laminate when I was hammering to make things flush where the two mitered counter-tops are joined together.  The crack is about 3 inches long towards the back.  It's not extremely noticeable but it's driving me nuts.  Can this be fixed with some type of seam filler?  I'll upload a picture tomorrow if need be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Picture please?  There are some laminate touch up seam filler...I think of them as paint but they're pretty doughy, maybe they could be used to fill?  Maybe sand them down to match the height? SeamFil or the like.

Answer (score 1):

There is a seam filler to hide a seam not sure if this will work well on a crack. The other thing I have used are solvents acetone and MEK. The problem with solvents is they can really make a mess (I have only tried a few times to use solvents acetone gave the best results but the seam filler gell did work the best for me.

I have never hammered laminate. After fitting a pieces and pre-gluing, I use window blind slats they allow the pre glued sheet to be put in place then I pull the slat closest to a Seam and make sure it fits then pull the slats and use a roller to push the top down into the glue. The filler gell I have used is designed to seal but it comes in colors to match as the gel has a little volume I don’t know if it will work for a crack in the material but I would check it out. Acetone may help but I have not had results that looked as good as the filler /sealer made by the laminate manufacturer. If you use a solvent a syringe or eye dropper will help control the amount put a drop in the crack and it will run down the crack (I understand this is horizontal) don’t add two much or it will make a mess as I did in the past.

Use a couple of small scraps to practice I got to where I could hide a seam but not as well as the filler that matched. Two much will pull the contact cement / glue up and that’s when it has to be redone.